# Is it possible to keep a service at 300 [service] priority?

Tags: android, android-service

I am currently working on an application that requires a service to keep a connection to an XMPP server. Testing has shown that the service runs at Service level priority [300] at start-up but after opening the application and finishing all activities it runs at Background priority [400].

My understanding of the documentation is that the service should have a higher priority than processes that are in the background. Is it possible to ensure that the priority of a service stays at 300 priority?

I would like to be able to do this to reduce the overhead cost of restarting the XMPP connection when the service restarts. I'm also trying to avoid using foreground service for to minimise UI clutter.

Comment: Where are you getting these numbers?

Comment: Pulled from ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo importance field

Answer (score 0):

> Testing has shown that the service runs at Service level priority [300] at start-up but after opening the application and finishing all activities it runs at Background priority [400].

That is not priority. That is `importance`. There is a difference.

Presumably, your service is not running, which is why the process fell to `IMPORTANCE_BACKGROUND` from `IMPORTANCE_SERVICE`.

> Is it possible to ensure that the priority of a service stays at 300 priority?

I'd focus on making sure that the service itself is running and has not been destroyed.